# String pointer issue in C code

Tags: c

This C program reads a line of text from keyboard and then writes the longest word in the line. The issue with my code below is that it only prints the last word apart from its length, although everything seems fine. Can anyone see a problem with my code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 132
#define MAXW 30

int Len_w[MAXW];
int Max_V(int vf[], int len);

main()
{
    char s[MAX+1], w[MAXW], *Ind_w[MAXW],*p,out[MAXW];
    int k=0, i=0, Maximum, g=0;
    printf("\nInsert the line....\n");
    p=fgets(s, MAX, stdin);

    while(sscanf(p, "%s%n", w, &k)==1){
        Len_w[i] = strlen(w);
        Ind_w[i] = w; //the issue is here!!
        p+=k+1;
        i++;
    }
    Maximum = Max_V(Len_w,i);

    for(g=0;g<i;g++){
        if(Len_w[g] == Maximum){
                //sscanf(Ind_w[g],"%s",out);
                printf("\n%s", Ind_w[g]);


            }
    }

    return 0;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int Max_V(int vf[], int len)
{
  int j; int Max;
  Max=*vf;

  for(j=1; j < len; j++)
  {
     if(*(vf+j) > Max)
     {
         Max=*(vf + j);
     }
  }

  return Max;
}
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: Pointer arithmetic is fun, but regular indexing tends to make such code more readable.

Answer (score 5):

```
Ind_w[i] = w;//the issue is here!!
```

You let all pointers in `Ind_w` point to the same buffer, which is overwritten for each entered word. So only the last entered word remains "visible".

If you have it,

```
Ind_w[i] = strdup(w);
```

is a simple solution. Otherwise

```
Ind_w[i] = malloc(strlen(w)+1);
strcpy(Ind_w[i], w);
```

Both ways require the pointed-to memory to be freed when it is no longer used.

Comment: Remember; you'll have to free the memory allocated by `strdup` or `malloc` yourself, afterwards.

Comment: can i ask something related to this matter through email

Comment: @maziarparsaeian I'd rather keep it on the site. What is it about?

Comment: it is another similar solution with no duplication that works but i do not get the point

Comment: it is written by one of the friends in my pc,that s why

Comment: @maziarparsaeian You could paste it on e.g. hpaste.org, or codepad.

Comment: @maziarparsaeian Ah, now I see what was intended. I thought the point was to get the words out of `s`, so then you need space to store them somewhere. If you only want pointers to their start, things are different.

Comment: can i write my simple code in one of the mentioned websites to guide me what is its problem?cause you guided me in a nice way

Comment: @maziarparsaeian Sure, paste it and ping me with the link. (Explain what the problem is somewhere, perhaps in comments in the code.)

Comment: @maziarparsaeian Okay, you omit some checks that could be necessary (name length and such), in `insertlist`, if the `sscanf` fails, you should `free` the pointer, in `main` you have the wrong condition in the `while` loop, `feof(fp)` is only true **after** you tried to read past the end of the file, it should be `while(fgets(buffer,100,fp))`. In `asc_sort`, you only give 10 characters for the `name`s, but there are 100 in the `struct nd`, that smells of a problem. Also, you use VLAs; since you're on Windows, that might be a problem (MSVC doesn't support C99 and VLAs), (cont)

Comment: And your sort only swaps elements with identical names (`if(strcmp(nam[j],nam[k])==0)`), so doesn't really sort the list elements. When swapping the `names`, you use index `i` instead of `k`, so that's probably an out-of-bounds access. Apart from that, nothing obvious. What's the exact problem?

Comment: the problems wants to sort the identity code of the elements if their names are equal so i put if(iden[j]>iden[k]) after checking the names,i is the total read number of elements and I changed what you mentioned but still the code does not work for the asc_sort function

Comment: @maziarparsaeian That's not very precise. In what way doesn't it work? I suspect you want the entire list sorted by name, and then the parts with identical names sorted by id?

Comment: yes that is the real problem but i changed it in that way to make it simpler though it didnt work and i have no one to ask any help for my exam

Comment: Then `if ((sc = strcmp(nam[j], nam[k])) > 0 || (sc == 0 && iden[j] > iden[k])) { swap stuff }` should work.

Comment: the program hangs and makes execution error as before,something is wrong with the memory allocation i suppose

Comment: Works here with the changes. I suspect it's the VLAs. Compile with all warnings turned on to see what the compiler thinks, and try to use `malloc`, also, you could choose a big enough constant instead of `m` for the array dimensions to check that.

Comment: how to use malloc for *nam[m] array of pointers? nam[m] =(char *)malloc( m*(sizeof(char)))??does not work :-(

Comment: `char **nam = malloc(m * sizeof *nam);`, and for `matr`, use `char (*matr)[100] = malloc(m * sizeof *matr);`, cast the `malloc` result to the declared type if and only if your code must be compilable as C++.

Comment: thank you for all the guidelines but it doesnt work finally,as before error execution

Comment: @maziarparsaeian What kind of error? Can you paste the updated code?

Comment: after printing the i is equal to... the program stops working

Comment: [Here](http://codepad.org/P9VTbb6R), you haven't replaced `i` with `k` in the name-swapping part, and you didn't allocate space for the names, and you placed the `malloc`s in the filling loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
Ind_w[i] = strdup(w);//the issue is here!!
```

You have to duplicate the `w` buffer each time you read the buffer and not use the same buffer for all reading. with the way you did you will have all the array elements pointing to the same buffer and this buffer is containing the same string which is the last one read with `sscanf`

**Note:** you have to `free` all the duplicated buffers when they come useless. You can do it by go over the array of pointers and free each element (pointer)